# Insert data into SQLite Database Browser

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm using Eclipse ADT . I want to do something whereby when I press this button , information like Username , Longitude , Latitude are stored in a table created using SQLite Database Browser . I understand from my teacher that I have to use something like insert sql or something like that . But I'm really new to android and not sure what the full code is . Anyone can help me with this ?

I've seen questions like upsert and not insert or update , but I don't know the difference .

Comment: Refer this [http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) and [http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: Do I have to do all those ? Because my table have a long list of columns . What I doing now is using a local database in my assets . And further on , I would be using taking the database from the server .

Comment: ok You mean your DB coming from Assets but what about Data? Do you insert a data on run time? and where the data is coming from?

Comment: Yes , my DB is coming from the Assets file . The Data are all inside the DB . I wanna insert it on run time . Which means once the button is pressed , the username keyed in and the current longitude and latitude will be captured and stored inside another table inside the DB .

Comment: then first of all you need to copy that DB from `Assets` to your `/data/data/yourPKG/databases/` folder and create `DBHelper` class to handle your different `Table` data insertion

Comment: I've got the DB into the databases already and got DataBaseHelper . But not too sure if my DataBaseHelper is right .

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont nead to copy data from db in asset to new DB ,just copy your db in asset to DB location in android using following code.

### Full code for Class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class MYDB {


Context c;
public DbHelpr dbhlpr;

String DB_NAME="DB.db";
int DB_VERSION=1;
int count,j;
public String DB_PATH;
public MYDB(Context c) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c=c;

    dbhlpr=new DbHelpr(c);


//  dbReadable=dbhlpr.getReadableDatabase();

}
public void close()
{
    dbhlpr.close();


}
public class DbHelpr extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelpr(Context c) 
    {
        super(c, DB_NAME,null, DB_VERSION);

        DB_PATH = c.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

        createDataBase()    ;
    }

    public void createDataBase() 
    {
         boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
            if(!mDataBaseExist)
            {

                copyDatabase();
            }

    }

     //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //system.out.println("DB file: "+DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput =   c.getAssets().open("DB_NAME.EXTENSION");

        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();        

    }  

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}




public int readDBTableFieldCount(String table) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);      
    int count=cr.getCount();
    cr.close();
    db.close();
    return count;
}

private void insertDataTo_rssFeed(int _id, int title_id, int sub_id,String title, int url) 
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put("_id",_id);
    cv.put("title_id", title_id);
    cv.put("sub_id", sub_id);
    cv.put("title",title);
    cv.put("url",url);
    long res=this.writeDBTable(cv, "t_rssfeed");

}

public Cursor readDBTable(String table) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.query(table, null, null, null, null, null, null);      
    return cr;
}

public Cursor readMatchingRows(String table,String column1,String column2,String value1,int value2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cr=db.rawQuery("select * from " + table + " where " + column1 + "='" + value1+"' and "+column2+ "="+value2 , null);
    return cr;
}



public long writeDBTable(ContentValues cv,String table)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sdb=dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase();
    long res=sdb.insert(table, null, cv);
    sdb.close();
    return res;
}

public float delete(String table,String colmName,String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] arr={data};
    colmName=colmName+"=?";
    float res=db.delete(table, colmName,arr );
    db.close();
    return res;
}


 public void myDBUpdate(String tableName,String keyField,ContentValues cv, String KeyValue) 
{
        String[] col={KeyValue};            
        SQLiteDatabase db=dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase();
        keyField=keyField+"=?";
        long res=db.update(tableName, cv, keyField, col);
        db.close();
}



 }
```

Comment: Where am I suppose to put this chuck of code into ? DBAdapter ? DBHelper ? or MainActivity ?

Comment: this is a template for your class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper remove the unwanted functions and add your other functions to this and replace your class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper with this